# How to force material-ui to generate !important css styles to prevent WordPress/Gutenberg css style clashes?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, wordpress-gutenberg, jss

I like to write an WordPress plugin extending the Gutenberg Editor. The plugin uses material-ui to render it's ui.

Unfortunately the material-ui generated css style selectors have a lower priority than some of the Gutenberg css styles. This has the result of mixed css application of both Gutenberg and material-ui css which looks really ugly :-)

How can I configure material-ui to generate styles having a higher priority than Gutenberg css styles ?

One solution could be suffixing every generated css value with "!important". Better option would be to prefix every material-ui generated css rule with an more specific css selector than the Gutenberg styles.

How can I do that using material-ui ?